# SQL Server collation to MySQL collation+character set mapping and vice versa

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to **automatically** translate SQL Server collation string to MySQL collation string.  But I can't find any rules, how are these collation names created.

For example, I want to translate MySQL collation 'big5_chinese_ci' into SQL Server  equivalent.

There are some useful links:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258233(v=sql.80).aspx
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Any ideas? (btw...please excuse my bad english)